# FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource()) gives null

Tags: javafx, testfx

I'm trying to make tests using TestFX. But when calling this code I get an error.

```
@ExtendWith(ApplicationExtension.class)
class HelloApplicationTest extends ApplicationTest {
    public double x, y;

    @Start
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("fxml/Home.fxml")));
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);


        root.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            x = stage.getX() - event.getSceneX();
            y = stage.getY() - event.getSceneY();
        });

        root.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            stage.setX(event.getSceneX() + x);
            stage.setY(event.getSceneY() + y);
        });

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 606, 614));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Error:

```
--- Exception in Async Thread ---
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:116)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    org.testfx.framework.junit5.ApplicationExtension$AnnotationBasedApplicationFixture.start(ApplicationExtension.java:158)
    org.testfx.framework.junit5.ApplicationAdapter.start(ApplicationAdapter.java:37)
    org.testfx.toolkit.impl.ApplicationServiceImpl.lambda$start$0(ApplicationServiceImpl.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    javafx.graphics@20-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    javafx.graphics@20-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    javafx.graphics@20-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    javafx.graphics@20-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    javafx.graphics@20-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:183)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:233)
    HelloApplicationTest.start(HelloApplicationTest.java:28)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    org.testfx.framework.junit5.ApplicationExtension$AnnotationBasedApplicationFixture.start(ApplicationExtension.java:158)
    org.testfx.framework.junit5.ApplicationAdapter.start(ApplicationAdapter.java:37)
    org.testfx.toolkit.impl.ApplicationServiceImpl.lambda$start$0(ApplicationServiceImpl.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    javafx.graphics@20-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    javafx.graphics@20-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    javafx.graphics@20-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    javafx.graphics@20-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    javafx.graphics@20-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:183)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
--- Trace of caller of unhandled exception in Async Thread ---
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:2550)
    org.testfx.util.WaitForAsyncUtils$ASyncFXCallable.<init>(WaitForAsyncUtils.java:650)
    org.testfx.util.WaitForAsyncUtils.asyncFx(WaitForAsyncUtils.java:258)
    org.testfx.toolkit.impl.ApplicationServiceImpl.start(ApplicationServiceImpl.java:48)
    org.testfx.toolkit.impl.ToolkitServiceImpl.lambda$setupApplication$6(ToolkitServiceImpl.java:127)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:577)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)

--- Exception in Async Thread ---
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    org.testfx.util.WaitForAsyncUtils$ASyncFXCallable.get(WaitForAsyncUtils.java:697)
    org.testfx.toolkit.impl.ToolkitServiceImpl.lambda$setupApplication$6(ToolkitServiceImpl.java:127)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:577)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:116)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    org.testfx.framework.junit5.ApplicationExtension$AnnotationBasedApplicationFixture.start(ApplicationExtension.java:158)
    org.testfx.framework.junit5.ApplicationAdapter.start(ApplicationAdapter.java:37)
    org.testfx.toolkit.impl.ApplicationServiceImpl.lambda$start$0(ApplicationServiceImpl.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    javafx.graphics@20-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    javafx.graphics@20-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    javafx.graphics@20-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    javafx.graphics@20-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    javafx.graphics@20-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:183)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:233)
    HelloApplicationTest.start(HelloApplicationTest.java:28)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    org.testfx.framework.junit5.ApplicationExtension$AnnotationBasedApplicationFixture.start(ApplicationExtension.java:158)
    org.testfx.framework.junit5.ApplicationAdapter.start(ApplicationAdapter.java:37)
    org.testfx.toolkit.impl.ApplicationServiceImpl.lambda$start$0(ApplicationServiceImpl.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    javafx.graphics@20-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    javafx.graphics@20-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    javafx.graphics@20-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    javafx.graphics@20-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    javafx.graphics@20-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:183)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
--- Trace of caller of unhandled exception in Async Thread ---
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:2550)
    org.testfx.util.WaitForAsyncUtils$ASyncFXCallable.<init>(WaitForAsyncUtils.java:650)
    org.testfx.util.WaitForAsyncUtils.async(WaitForAsyncUtils.java:193)
    org.testfx.toolkit.impl.ToolkitServiceImpl.setupApplication(ToolkitServiceImpl.java:123)
    org.testfx.api.FxToolkit.setupApplication(FxToolkit.java:153)
    org.testfx.framework.junit5.ApplicationExtension.beforeEach(ApplicationExtension.java:85)
    org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachCallbacks$2(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:163)
    org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:199)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:199)
    org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:162)
    org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:129)
    org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)


java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

    at org.testfx.util.WaitForAsyncUtils.waitFor(WaitForAsyncUtils.java:302)
    at org.testfx.api.FxToolkit.waitForSetup(FxToolkit.java:245)
    at org.testfx.api.FxToolkit.setupApplication(FxToolkit.java:153)
    at org.testfx.framework.junit5.ApplicationExtension.beforeEach(ApplicationExtension.java:85)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachCallbacks$2(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:163)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:199)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:162)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:129)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.testfx.util.WaitForAsyncUtils$ASyncFXCallable.get(WaitForAsyncUtils.java:697)
    at org.testfx.toolkit.impl.ToolkitServiceImpl.lambda$setupApplication$6(ToolkitServiceImpl.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:577)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:116)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.testfx.framework.junit5.ApplicationExtension$AnnotationBasedApplicationFixture.start(ApplicationExtension.java:158)
    at org.testfx.framework.junit5.ApplicationAdapter.start(ApplicationAdapter.java:37)
    at org.testfx.toolkit.impl.ApplicationServiceImpl.lambda$start$0(ApplicationServiceImpl.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at javafx.graphics@20-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@20-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics@20-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics@20-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@20-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:183)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:233)
    at HelloApplicationTest.start(HelloApplicationTest.java:28)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    ... 12 more
```

As if it couldn't find the Home.fxml file. Here is the hierarchy of the project:

[image: hierarchy]

I tried to give a different file path, but I can't find it. Instead of getClass().getResource() I tried HelloApplication.class.getResource() but to no avail.

Comment: More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61531317/230513).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine the correct path for FXML files, CSS files, Images, and other resources needed by my JavaFX Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other)

Comment: Off-topic, but I don't recommend using the `-ea` versions of the JavaFX software unless you are testing your code for compatibility with upcoming new features or bug fixes that are currently only provided in the early access versions.

Comment: `HelloApplicationTest` is not in a package.  You are looking up the resources relative to the `HelloApplicationTest` class location.  Your FXML location, relative to the `HelloApplicationTest` class, is at `com/example/kalkulator/fxml`. If using a relative location, I suggest coding the class name, rather than calling `getClass()`.  So, to find the FXML, you would use:  `HelloApplicationTest.class.getResource("com/example/kalkulator/fxml/Home.fxml")`.